# Graph-like problem

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

> Each shop in a town has an odd number of customers and each pair of shops shares an even number of customers. Prove that there are at least as many customers as there are shops.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Is this the right way round? 1 shop with 3 customers satisfies the conditions, and yet has more customers than shops.

Comment: @user73985: you are right, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a folklore problem, and the usual solution involves linear algebra. Let's denote the number of shops and customers by $n$ and $m$ respectively.

**Hint 1:**

> Let the signature of a shop be a $0/1$ vector of length $m$, where $1$ indicates that the relevant person is a customer of that shop. 
>
>  Notice that if the vectors are interpreted as elements of $\mathbb{F}_2^m$, then \begin{align}\langle v_i,v_i\rangle &= 1,\\\langle v_i,v_j\rangle &= 0,\end{align}
>  where $\langle x,y\rangle$ denotes the dot product of $x$ and $y$.

**Hint 2:**

> In fact they are all together independent:
>  \begin{align}\left\langle\sum_{i}a_iv_i,v_k\right\rangle = \langle a_kv_k,v_k\rangle = a_k\langle v_k,v_k\rangle = a_k\end{align}
>  so \begin{align} \sum_{i}a_iv_i = \mathbf{0} \implies a_k = \langle\mathbf{0},v_k\rangle = 0 \text{ for all  } k.\end{align}

**Hint 3:**

> If vector space has $n$ linearly independent vectors, then the dimension of that space must be at least $n$. Dimension of our space is $m$, hence $m \geq n$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Does that mean that avoiding usage of LA on non-real fields follows the solution along the same principles, just a longer one and less elegant?

Comment: @S.D. There surely is some graph-theoretic solution, but it seems as this problem was crafted to demonstrate use of $\mathbb{F}_2$-based linear algebra. In other words, I think that any nice solution would use similar techniques (perhaps in different wording or formulation).

Comment: Thank you! I am not well familiar with LA on non-real fields, so I wondered whether the step in Hint 2 does hold for any field. That is, from Hint 1 we seem to have a collection of mutually orthogonal vectors in some Euclidean space. Does not this automatically imply this collection is linearly independent?

Comment: @S.D. This is true for pairwise orthogonal vectors of _non-zero length_. To see this, you could try to perform Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization and observe that one subtracts nothing, because the orthogonality would make each component zero, and you end up with the same set you started.

Comment: Surely, non-zero, thanks again.